# Fetch data server side before returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, request, hapi.js

Using Hapi and React, what would be the best way to fetch data server side to generate your views?

I'm currently using Elasticsearch as my datasource and querying it using the `request` library, but given javascripts asynchronous natures, the data is never loaded on time, how can I have then data be loaded before I return the view?

```
// search
var React = require('react');
var request = require('request');

var options = {url: 'someWebSite.com',
   headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json;'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({
      'data' : 'someData'
   })
};

var data;
request.get(options, function (error, response){
  data = response.body;
})

var Default = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      //html involving data retrieved from service
    );
  }
});
module.exports = Default;
```

Comment: I don't know the ```request``` library, but I would imagine you just need to create your React Default component within a success callback function after the request.get() completes.

Answer (score 0):

I would get data from within hapi server and then use to populate your view, in your case react.  I would get data from external http source in a pre handler which can then used by view.  You cannot use module.exports to export an asynchronous context as "require" is synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using redux-saga to help you fetch the initial data on server side.

Never used Elasticsearch but check out from my [React example that uses Redux Saga and Hapi for Server-side Rendering](https://github.com/codeBelt/hapi-react-hot-loader-example)

Answer (score -1):

React **should be notified** somehow about update of its dependency values.

React components depend on `props` and `state` and things outside scope.

- `props` in component can be changed only if parent component pass new props object
- `state` can be updated with `.setState`
- `globals` (everything except `props` and `state`) can update React element:

  - Copy it to `state` and update it with some subscription methods in globals.
  - Use its values directly, and call `.forceUpdate` on component, again, by subscribing to global updates
  - Rerender root component with new `props`

In your case I would advise you to use one of the following:

- Use [Kefir.js](http://rpominov.github.io/kefir) (or similar) and [bind](https://github.com/iofjuupasli/kefir-react) *Observable* updates to *props*
- Put such queries in root [component](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html)
- Use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [ReFlux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs) and look for tutorials on how data sync done with that libraries